# How to find the reason for which an interop dll is generated by the project

Tags: xml, visual-c++, dll, interop

I am upgrading my project from `msxml4` to `msxml6`. It is a VC++ project, and I can see a dll
`Interop.MSXML2.4.0` is getting generated every time I build the project. Its properties says that its Version is 4.0.0. So, am not sure if my app will expect `msxml4` dll in the system during runtime. How can I find 'Why the dll `Interop.MSXML2.4.0` is getting generated' what are the things I should check for..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only happens in a C++/CLI project, not a C++ project.  You added a reference to the type library for msxml4 and it is translated into a .NET interop assembly so the CLR can use the COM interfaces in that component.

Right-click your project, Properties, Common Properties, Framework and References node.  You should see the Interop.MSXML2.4.0 there.  Select it and click the Remove Reference button.  If you didn't do so yet, click Add New References, COM tab and select "Microsoft XML, v6.0" to get the interop assembly for msxml6.

If this is in fact a pure C++ project then you should not be doing this at all.  You'd use the #import directive instead.